# Hash Index Vs NUSI - Teradata

Tags: database, indexing, teradata

Hash Index and NUSI both have sub-tables. And both can be value ordered and hash ordered. Then what exactly difference is between them?

Comment: A hash index is more synonymous/related to a single table join index. There is some similarity between a hash index and a secondary index but they are so much more like a single table join index that it feels odd to compare the Hash and Secondary indexes to each other. There's a [really good write up here](https://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/Database_Management/B035-1094-160K/xbc1472240588735.html) about Hash Indexes and how they compare and contrast with both Single Table Join Indexes and Secondary Indexes (not just NUSI).

Comment: Let me read. Thanks for Reply.